# Сафари ругается syntaxerror: Expected an identifier but found "images" instead

Tags: javascript, safari

Сафари ругается `syntaxerror: Expected an identifier but found "images" instead`

на этот JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" async>
    window.onload = function() {
        let images = [...document.getElementsByTagName("img")];
        for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].classList.add("lazyload");
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Вот на эту строчку         `for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {`
Помогите исправить, спасибо

Comment: Вы уверены, что именно на эту строчку ругается? Проверил у себя - ошибок нет. Вместо `[...document.getElementsByTagName("img")]` можно просто `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
```